# Replacing div content with an external file from within an external file loaded in said div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a file, say 'file1.html', loaded into a div via jQuery `$('#info').load('info/file1.html');` I want to change the content of #info from within file1 so file1.html looks like this:

```
<a href="#" onclick="loadFile(this.value);" value="file2">File2</a>
```

where

```
function loadFile(f) {
    $('#info').load('info/'+f+'.html');
}
```

However, I only get a blank page in the div after the click. I also tried removing the `'info/'` if the folder setup broke it but nothing. What's wrong?

Comment: have you console.log(f)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that anchor tag dom objects (`HTMLAnchorElement`) don't have a "value" property set on them. To get at the value attribute of the anchor tag that the dom object represents, you can do `$(this).attr('value')` (instead of `this.value`, which will just be undefined).

But really, you should be attaching your event using an id/class and jquery, not by using an onclick attribute. And you should be calling your anchor attribute `data-value`, not `value`, to conform to HTML5 specs on custom attributes. So the better way to do this would be:

HTML:

```
<a href="#" id="file-loader" data-value="file2">File2</a>
```

Javascript:

```
$('#file-loader').click(function(ev) {
    $('#info').load('info/' + $(this).attr('data-value') + '.html');
    ev.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: This one worked beautifully, you get your accepted answer in 4 minutes. Thank you sire!

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
  <a href="#" onclick="loadFile('file2');">File2</a>
```

Comment: It used to load a blank page before, now it doesn't load anything at all?